# Capybara failing with ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, capybara

I'm doing integration tests with Capybara on a Ionic app that use rails in backend, and I'm having a problem after I signin successfully, the second `visit` does nothing and I have a `timeout while waiting for angular`.

```
# test_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join("test/helpers/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

if ENV['VIEW_IN_BROWSER'] == "true"
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
  end
else
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end

Capybara.server_port = 3000 # serveur rails en mode test
Capybara.always_include_port = true
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
Capybara.raise_server_errors = false

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Capybara::Angular::DSL

  def setup
    super
  end

  def teardown
    super
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

My helper :

```
#test/helpers/ionic_helper.rb
module IonicHelper
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  def on_ionic_app
    Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:5000' # Serveur ionic
    begin
      yield
    rescue => error
      puts error
    ensure
      Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:4321' # serveur ionic en mode intégration continue
    end
  end

  def user_log_in
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit(Capybara.app_host+"/#/app/signin")
    fill_in "email", with: user.email
    fill_in "password", with: user.password
    click_on "Connexion"
  end
end
```

The **first problem** is that I have to specify `Capybara.app_host` to the `visit` mehod to hit the good ionic port (5000) I cannot figure why.

My **second problem** is is this test :

```
# reseau_test.rb
require "test_helper"

class ReseauTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include IonicHelper

  test "On s'assure que tous les elements en mode connecté soient présents" do
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver

    on_ionic_app do
      user_log_in
      visit(Capybara.app_host+"/#/app/network")
      assert page.has_css?('span.count.following.text-center.ng-binding'), "Il doit y avoir un chiffre pour le nombre d'abonnements"
      assert page.has_content?('Abonnements'), "Il doit y avoir le texte 'Abonnements'"
      assert page.has_css?('span.count.follower.ng-binding'), "Il doit y avoir un chiffre pour le nombre d'abonnés"
      assert page.has_content?('Abonnés'), "Il doit y avoir le texte 'Abonnés'"
    end 
  end

end
```

If I remove `user_log_in` the tests work fine, but this page have to be seen with a logged user, and when I test it, it fails with `timeout while waiting for angular`. I can put the `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to 30 it fails the same way.

Comment: Does your second problem occur with both selenium and poltergeist? If so - what shows in the browser with selenium.

Comment: Yes, the problem occur with both. With selenium, the browser just show the good redirected page (after login), do not go to the second visit link, wait (depends on default_max_wait_time) and quit.

Comment: Updated my answer with a second part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem:  The reason you're having issues with app_host is because you're specifying `Capybara.always_include_port = true`.  What this does is force the port being visited to be set to the port Capybara is running a server on unless the address passed to `visit` has a non-default port specified.  Since it doesn't look like you ever want `visit` to connect directly to the server being run by Capybara you should set remove it or set it to `Capybara.always_include_port = false`.  With it false you can just set Capybara.app_host as needed and it should be used as the default start for `visit`

Your second issue is being caused by the JS capybara-angular is running in the page never showing the page as ready.  Check for errors in your JS that could be preventing capybara-angular to have issues, or look at https://github.com/wrozka/capybara-angular/issues/20